# Run code in Vagrantfile only if provisioning

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I want to display some text on the screen when running `vagrant up` (or `vagrant provision`, etc.) ***if and only if*** provisioning is being done.  (For `vagrant up` it is only run the first time, or if specifically forced with `--provision`.)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a shell provisioner is probably the easiest solution, with the small cost that it is executed on the VM over SSH.

Another option is to use the [vagrant-host-shell](https://github.com/phinze/vagrant-host-shell) plugin:

```rb
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  # other config and provisioners
  # [...]

  config.vm.provision :host_shell, inline: 'echo "Provisioned!"'
end
```

If you like over-engineering, you can even make your own plugin in Vagrantfile. ;)

```rb
class EchoPlugin < Vagrant.plugin('2')
  class EchoAction
    def initialize(app, env)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      @app.call(env)
      puts "Provisioned!"
    end
  end

  name 'echo'

  action_hook 'echo' do |hook|
    hook.before Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Provision, EchoAction
  end
end

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Awesome.  I think I may write my own plugin just for the fun of it.

Comment: Take a look at e.g. the vagrant-host-shell code for an example how to do it a cleaner way than in Vagrantfile. The text could be a configuration option etc.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Vagrant issue #7043](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7043) where somebody wanted to use `@env[:provision_enabled]` to see if provisioning is being run. It was answered that you could also check the arguments your Vagrantfile was called with:

> This is not currently possible because the Vagrantfile is parsed before the environment is created. This information is available to
>   provisioners and plugins, but not the Vagrantfile itself because of
>   the load ordering. In other words, that `@env` doesn't exist until after
>   all Vagrantfile's have been parsed, and unfortunately that's a hard
>   requirement because information in the Vagrantfile determines the way
>   that object is created. It's a catch-22 for your use case.
>
> One possible alternative is to inspect `ARGV` in your Vagrantfile.
>   Something like:
>
> ```
> if ARGV.include?("up") || (ARGV.include?("reload") && ARGV.include?("--provision")) 
>     ... 
> end
> ```

## Example usage

I added two functions to the bottom of my Vagrantfile:

```
def provisioned?(vm_name='default', provider='virtualbox')
  File.exists?(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),".vagrant/machines/#{vm_name}/#{provider}/action_provision"))
end

def explicit_provisioning?()
   (ARGV.include?("reload") && ARGV.include?("--provision")) || ARGV.include?("provision")
end
```

Which I can use around any statement in my Vagrantfile:

```
if (not provisioned?) || explicit_provisioning?
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to show a text message *if and only if* provisioning runs, and you already know that provisioning runs only on first `vagrant up` and when forcing it using the `--provision` switch - then why not just add the output of the message to the provisioning itself?

This could be as simple as using a shell provisioner and running an `echo` command inside of that.

As Vagrant supports multiple provisioners within one Vagrantfile and is able to run all of them when provisioning a virtual machine, this is a dead-easy step, no matter whether you use the shell provisioner anyway, or if you use any other provisioner.